# unknown request using express

Tags: node.js, express

I installed the `nginx`(Port 80 connection passed to express 3000 port) and `express` apps on AWS lightsail. Sometimes an unknown request occurs. like..

```
GET /_ignition/execute-solution
GET /config/getuser?index=0
GET /owa/auth/logon.aspx?url=https%3a%2f%2f1%2fecp%2f
GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
...more...
```

There were mainly many requests for php. these requests end with a 404 response.
All my API use JWT authentication. Is `express` safe for these requests? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: it's probably your app is getting scanned

Comment: Does it matter if my app is scanned?